# Pig running with thread

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, apigee, fishpig

I'm trying to load the data from the local dir to pig using the command

**records = load '/home/hduser/Downloads/1901' as (year:chararray,temperature:int, quality:int);**

**dump records;**
This works fine.

while I try the next command

**filtered_records = filter records by temperature != 9999 AND (quality == 0 OR quality == 1 OR quality == 4 OR quality == 5 OR quality == 9);**

**dump filtered_records;**

This shows the following message with some thread

```
2015-05-05 19:59:50,998 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.optimizer.PruneColumns - No column pruned for records
2015-05-05 19:59:50,999 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.optimizer.PruneColumns - No map keys pruned for records
2015-05-05 19:59:51,102 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
2015-05-05 19:59:51,294 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - (Name: Store(file:/tmp/temp138869802/tmp-1519406150:org.apache.pig.builtin.BinStorage) - 1-90 Operator Key: 1-90)
2015-05-05 19:59:51,380 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2015-05-05 19:59:51,393 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2015-05-05 19:59:51,457 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2015-05-05 19:59:51,460 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2015-05-05 19:59:51,465 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2015-05-05 19:59:52,893 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up single store job
2015-05-05 19:59:53,042 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2015-05-05 19:59:53,043 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2015-05-05 19:59:53,047 [Thread-4] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient - Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
2015-05-05 19:59:53,259 [Thread-4] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2015-05-05 19:59:53,323 [Thread-4] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2015-05-05 19:59:53,377 [Thread-4] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2015-05-05 19:59:53,385 [Thread-4] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1
2015-05-05 19:59:53,549 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
2015-05-05 19:59:53,860 [Thread-13] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2015-05-05 19:59:53,869 [Thread-13] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2015-05-05 19:59:53,870 [Thread-13] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1
2015-05-05 19:59:53,953 [Thread-13] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2015-05-05 19:59:53,957 [Thread-13] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2015-05-05 19:59:53,996 [Thread-13] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2015-05-05 19:59:54,024 [Thread-13] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2015-05-05 19:59:54,323 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - HadoopJobId: job_local_0001
2015-05-05 19:59:54,893 [Thread-13] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner - Task:attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
2015-05-05 19:59:54,901 [Thread-13] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2015-05-05 19:59:54,901 [Thread-13] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - 
2015-05-05 19:59:54,902 [Thread-13] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner - Task attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
2015-05-05 19:59:54,907 [Thread-13] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2015-05-05 19:59:54,957 [Thread-13] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter - Saved output of task 'attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0' to file:/tmp/temp138869802/tmp-1519406150
2015-05-05 19:59:54,958 [Thread-13] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - 
2015-05-05 19:59:54,958 [Thread-13] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner - Task 'attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0' done.
2015-05-05 19:59:58,829 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2015-05-05 19:59:58,830 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Successfully stored result in: "file:/tmp/temp138869802/tmp-1519406150"
2015-05-05 19:59:58,833 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Records written : 0
2015-05-05 19:59:58,837 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Bytes written : 0
2015-05-05 19:59:58,837 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
2015-05-05 19:59:58,837 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Proactive spill count : 0
2015-05-05 19:59:58,837 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Success!
2015-05-05 19:59:58,920 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2015-05-05 19:59:58,930 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2015-05-05 19:59:58,933 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1
```

I can't see any output. help me fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should define your loader, like:

```
records = load '/home/hduser/Downloads/1901'  Using PigStorage(',') as (year:chararray,temperature:int, quality:int);
```

To have the data correctly in your records table according to the schem you defined.
(Please use the correct loader function, if you're using a csv or tsv than update PigStorage's separator character for that what your're using in your data file)

Comment: Thanks for you help. It works fine... but the same thread message is showing. how can I fix it.